# MySQL 5.5 Unexpected "End_of_input"

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to MySQL but have very good understanding of MSSQL (was a DBA but haven't coded in SQL in probably 4/5 years).

I'm working on a cursor but before I even got to the cursor I got stuck with an "Unexpected 'end_of_input'" error.

Below is my very basic code. I have 2 errors (as mentioned above) at the end of my last 'OR' statement (OR PublicationKeywords LIKE "%Gross Domestic Product%";) and the END; statement.

```
drop procedure if exists myCurs;

CREATE PROCEDURE myCurs ()

BEGIN

    INSERT INTO km_curs_test_temp
    SELECT PNumber, PublicationName, PublicationKeywords 
    FROM `cl_Releases`
    WHERE PNumber LIKE "%Gross Domestic Product%" 
    OR PublicationName LIKE "%Gross Domestic Product%" 
    OR PublicationKeywords LIKE "%Gross Domestic Product%";

END
```

I'm using MySQL 5.5 and WorkBench 6.0.

I'd appreciate any assistance you can throw my way.
I've spent the last few hours trying to figure this out without much progress.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a [delimiter](http://alextsilverstein.com/programming-and-development/mysql/mysql-the-reason-for-using-the-delimiter-statement-in-mysql-routines-stored-procedures-functions-triggers/)

```
drop procedure if exists myCurs;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE myCurs ()

BEGIN

    INSERT INTO km_curs_test_temp
    SELECT PNumber, PublicationName, PublicationKeywords 
    FROM `cl_Releases`
    WHERE PNumber LIKE "%Gross Domestic Product%"
    OR PublicationName LIKE "%Gross Domestic Product%"
    OR PublicationKeywords LIKE "%Gross Domestic Product%";
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Hi TJ, thank you. I guess I'll have to read up on the DELIMITER. The code, however, doesn't actually insert the found records (2 rows) into my table but if I run the 'INSERT... Select.. From' outside of the 'Create procedure' then the rows are inserted just fine. Can you spot my newbie mistake? The joys of working on a new platform....

Comment: That is strange. The procedure looks all right. How are you executing the procedure? `call myCurs;`?

Comment: Ahhh! I thought one can execute the entire script (including the Create Procedure) and it will execute the bits contained within. My mistake. I ran the call myCurs and my rows were inserted just fine - THANK YOU VERY MUCH. It's appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome. Create Procedure is like creating a function. Until you call it, it won't be executed. For reference, a lot of questions that people who are learning something new, come across, have already been answered on SO and are very well indexed by Google - could be of good help.